# Nextcloud: Configure onlyoffice connector app over command line

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, nextcloud, onlyoffice

I am in the process of creating an ansible role that will allow me to perform a completely unattended installation and configuration of the Onlyoffice document server and integrate it into Nextcloud. The installation of the document server will be done via a podman container. The installation of the connector app is done via Nextcloud occ.

What I am currently missing is a way to configure the Onlyoffice Connector app in Nextcloud via CLI.

I have already searched the Nextcloud installation path to see if there is a configuration file for the connector app somewhere here, but unfortunately I did not find it.
`Also occ onlyoffice:documentserver --help` does not give any possibility for configuration unfortunately.

What possibility do I have to configure the connector app completely via the CLI / bash?

Document Server version: 7.4.1.36
Connector version: 8.2.0
DMS (platform) version: Nextcloud Hub 6 (27.1.1)
OS: Debian 12 / AlmaLinux 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a few options available for customization such as

- ONLYOFFICE Docs address
- ONLYOFFICE Docs address for internal requests from NC
- NC address for internal requests from ONLYOFFICE Docs
- Secret key for JWT tockens

You can configure these oiptions [this way](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/docker-onlyoffice-nextcloud/blob/master/set_configuration.sh#L16-L19). (just an example of the OO docker compose)
Once the connector has been set up use `occ onlyoffice:documentserver --check` to make sure that ONLYOFFICE Document Server is successfully connected

Comment: That is everything that I need. Thank you for your answer.